# Vertically align an image included using CSS background property to a Span tag

Tags: html, css, icons, vertical-alignment

I have a span tag. **I'm loading an image inside this span tag using css**. **Now I wants to vertically centre this image inside the span tag**. I can't vertically centre this image because I'm applying this image to span using CSS. Here I'm using an icon sprite and extracting only relevant part from the icon-sprite. Can anyone help?

**HTML**

```
<span class="icon"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon{
   background: url(../images/icon-sprite.png) no-repeat -328px 0;
   width: 60px;
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute; 
}
```

I tried adding line-height to `.icon` class. But no joy.

Comment: have you tried adding css tranform like the below .icon {
  background: url(http://maddesigns.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IcoMoon-App-Icon-Font-Generator-2014-07-07-22-36-10-2014-07-07-22-36-15-825x510.png) no-repeat -328px 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;  
  position: absolute;
  transform:translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
   -moz-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
   -ms-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the numbers in order for it to work for your icon, but this should do the trick.

```css
.icon { 
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #FF0000;
  white-space: nowrap;
} 

.icon:before{
  content: "";
   position: relative;
   width:15px;
   display:inline-block;
}

.icon:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0; 
    margin-top: -8.5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px; 
    background: url('https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo127.png') no-repeat -0px -327px;

}
```

```html
<span class="icon" style="font-size:20px;">whatever</span>
<span class="icon" style="font-size:25px;">whatever</span>
<span class="icon" style="font-size:30px;">whatever</span>
<span class="icon" style="font-size:35px;">whatever</span>
<span class="icon" style="font-size:40px;">whatever</span>
<span class="icon" style="font-size:45px;">whatever</span>
```

The border and font size are just for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Can use anyone:

```
.icon{
   background: url(../images/icon-sprite.png) no-repeat;
   background-position:left center;
   width: 60px;
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute; 
}
```

or

```
.icon{
   background: url(../images/icon-sprite.png) no-repeat left center;
   width: 60px;
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: You can not.  no-repeat -328px 0 => it's a piece of a sprite

Comment: This styles won't work when you are using an icon-sprite. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally here, you should have a parent class and try to vertically align `.icon` to the parent.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
.icon {
  background: url(../images/icon-sprite.png) no-repeat -328px 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the span tag to be aligned inside div tag. I want to vertically align the image inside the span tag which is fixed.

Comment: You cannot. Since you are using a sprite here and have a fixed width and height to maintain none of the `background` properties like `background-position` etc will work. So what you should do is make the `span` the same height and width as the sprite required and align it with another parent `span` or `div`.